$L_2$-norm consistency of kernel density estimation
The consistency results for kernel density estimation which I can find are almost all for the $L_1$-norm or $L_\infty$-norm, like in Consistency of Robust Kernel Density Estimators or Consistency of the Kernel Density Estimator: A Survey. I can't simply generalize them to $L_2$-norm since on a infinite measure field like $\mathbb{R}$, the relation of $L_2$ and $L_1$ norm is unclear. So could anyone point me a consistency result for the $L_2$-norm?
